# create a new column in the table depending from other column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ddl

in my table, I got a column where is written the company code

```
example
DE06 or DE07
```

now I need to add a new column to this table where will have as value 'YES' for DE06 and 'NO' for DE07

I try to add a condition just for De06 but I cant make it work

```
ALTER Table dbo.DE06_PROJECT$
add [PROJECT_COMPANY_CODE2] nvarchar(50)   null 
GO
UPDATE dbo.DE06_PROJECT$ SET [PROJECT_COMPANY_CODE] ='YES'   where([COMPANY_CODE]='DE06')
GO
```

I need a new column [PROJECT_COMPANY_CODE2] with result 'YES' or 'NO' based on the value of the column [COMPANY_CODE]

I forget to mention that in the future I could need 3 possibilities 'YES' for DE06 and 'NO' for DE07 and 'MAYBE" for DE08

Comment: You shouldn't store data computed from other columns, will end up with data inconsistency. Either create a _view_, or use a _computed column_. (Or use triggers to manage the column.)

Comment: @jarlh how to create a computed column in this case

Answer (score 0):

If you have SQL Server then you can go for `CASE`

```
UPDATE dbo.DE06_PROJECT$ 
SET [PROJECT_COMPANY_CODE] = CASE WHEN [COMPANY_CODE]='DE06' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END
```

Comment: I forget to mention that in the future I could need 3 possibilities 'YES' for DE06 and 'NO' for DE07 and 'MAYBE" for DE08

Comment: You can add more when statements.  case [company_code] when 'de06' then 'yes' when 'de07' then 'no' when 'de08' then 'maybe' else 'unknown' end

Answer (score 0):

Use a *computed column* to ensure data consistency:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.DE06_PROJECT$
ADD [PROJECT_COMPANY_CODE] AS CASE [COMPANY_CODE] WHEN 'DE06' THEN 'YES'
                                                  WHEN 'DE07' THEN 'NO'
                                                  WHEN 'DE08' THEN 'MAYBE'
                                                  ELSE 'whatever' END
```